# Convexity of a set function

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Let $N$ be a finite set and $2^N$ be the set of all subsets of $N$. Consider the function $f:2^N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

$f$ is said to be *convex* if for any two $Q,S\in 2^N$
$$f(Q\cup S)\ge f(Q)+f(S)-f(Q\cap S).$$

However, I cannot recognize any connection with the notion of convexity of a function defined on the real line. Can you give any clue on how to interpret this particular sort of convexity?

---

**UPDATE:** As @Christoph rightfully noted, the described function is called supermodular (there is no entry on this kind of supermodular functions in Wikipedia, but I saw it elsewhere).

However, I'm still puzzled about the relation between sub(super)modular set functions and concave (convex) functions. In the article on submodular functions it is said that *"Submodular functions have properties which are very similar to convex and concave functions..."*

Does it mean that they are **both** convex and concave? What are these properties?

Comment: How do you compare two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, using $\le$ ?

Comment: @spkakkar When is he comparing subsets? He's comparing the values of $f$ (which are real numbers).

Comment: Note that the negative of this kind of set function is usually called [submodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function).

Comment: @Arthur, thanks. I see now that image of each subset is a real number.

Comment: https://theory.stanford.edu/~jvondrak/data/submod-tutorial-1.pdf